# SpamAssassin creating bayes.toks.expire text files

Tags: cpanel, bayesian, spamassassin

I have a shared hosting account at HostGator and have been using spamassassin for several months with no problem.  About 10 days ago, I logged in to cPanel > File Manager > .spamassassin folder, and there were 10-12 text files created like these:

```
bayes.toks.expire40422   2.99 MB
bayes.toks.expire42356   5.07 MB
bayes.toks.expire44593   5.07 MB
```

On average, about 2 new files like these are being created each day.  I can't open them in File Manager because the file size is too large and if I download a file to my pc and open it with Notepad, there is a lot there, but it is unreadable.

So far, there are also 3 other odd files being created about every 3-4 days like the following:

```
bayes.locl.gator.hostgator.com.15247   180 bytes
bayes.locl.gator.hostgator.com.28605   210 bytes
bayes.locl.gator.hostgator.com.78666   180 bytes
```

I searched Google and most posts are pretty old from 2006-2009 and none seem to have a clear answer other than stating these files can be manually deleted.  Naturally, I don't want to login every week to manually delete these files so I am trying to find out the cause and a resolution.

I submitted a support ticket to HostGator and their only reply was: 'This is caused due to spamassassin configuration', which does not help.

Also in the .spamassassin folder are these 3 related files:

```
bayes_journal   28 KB
bayes_seen   324 KB
bayes_toks   5.07 MB
```

I have the user_prefs file configured and working.  Does anyone know the cause of these files or how to prevent them in a shared hosting environment where I do not have direct access to the server?